# Connect to URL with socket.io-client

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have this demo setup:

- node.js WebSocket server #1 (using 'socket.io') running on port 8001
- node.js WebSocket server #2 (using 'socket.io') running on port 8002
- nginx websocket reverse proxy running on port 8000:

  redirecting any request to /wstest1/ to port 8001 (server #1)
  redirecting any request to /wstest2/ to port 8002 (server #2)

---

A node.js client (using **'socket.io-client'**, not a browser JavaScript client) tries to connect to server #1:

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('ws://localhost:8000/wstest1/');
```

but it can't connect. The nginx log says:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Feb/2015:16:16:04 +0100] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1423235764132-1&b64=1 HTTP/1.1" 404 168 "-" "node-XMLHttpRequest"
```

**so somewhere the path to `/wstest1/` got lost.**

How can I tell the socket.io-client it should connect to `/wstest1/` ?

---

nginx settings:

```
http {
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

    server {
        listen 8000;
        location /wstest1/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }
        location /wstest2/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8002;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

    }
}
```

---

Update: I just found this nice explanation (socket.io/docs/client-api/), why it doesn't work:

> A Socket instance is returned for the namespace specified by the
>   pathname in the URL, defaulting to /. For example, if the url is
>   http://localhost/users, a transport connection will be established to
>   http://localhost and a Socket.IO connection will be established to
>   /users.

Any workaround on this?

---

---

Shame on me. Classical case of RTFM / RTFC (C for code):

## SOLUTION:

Use the correct path:

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('ws://localhost:8000', {path: '/wstest1/socket.io'});
```

Use the correct nginx config:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8001/;
```

This little trailing `/` makes the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Set location in your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
location /wstest1 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8001;
}

location /wstest2 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8002;
}
```

See more:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Comment: I've already set the location. When I set location to "/", it works. But I want to have more than one WebSocket server running on the same port.

Comment: i can see you nginx server settings?

Answer (score 0):

See docs at http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/.

> Important note: The namespace is an implementation detail of the Socket.IO protocol, and is not related to the actual URL of the underlying transport, which defaults to /socket.io/….

If you want your socket.io endpoint to be hosted at '/wstest1' or '/wstest2' simply pass that as the 'path' parameter when you create your server.

Comment: Unfortunately, socket.io-client for node.js ignores the {path: ...} option

Comment: Oh, it does indeed support the {path: ...} option. See solution in OP.